# issues using Slim Framework Php error 404

Tags: php, slim

I recently stumbled on a piece of code that was using `Sim Framework` and it was impressive, not only did it hide the files but it also simplified work, unlike having multiple files, one could basically call a method, I do not know if php can do that by default but thats one of the main reason I want to use it, after hours of trying to make it work, well at least it worked but `post` has not worked, `get` did work though, I can't say its something to do with the index file or anything because the `get` method is in the same file as the get.

Here is requested complete code:

```
<?php

require_once '../include/DbOperation.php';
require '.././libs/Slim/Slim.php';

\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

/**
* Method is working 
*/
$app->get('/testing', function () {
echo 'testing Slim Framework'
 });


/**
 * Method is not working outputing Error 404 
*/

$app->post('/createstudent', function () use ($app) {
verifyRequiredParams(array('name', 'username', 'password'));
$response = array();
$name = $app->request->post('name');
$username = $app->request->post('username');
$password = $app->request->post('password');
$db = new DbOperation();
$res = $db->createStudent($name, $username, $password);
if ($res == 0) {
    $response["error"] = false;
    $response["message"] = "You are successfully registered";
    echoResponse(201, $response);
} else if ($res == 1) {
    $response["error"] = true;
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred while registereing";
    echoResponse(200, $response);
} else if ($res == 2) {
    $response["error"] = true;
    $response["message"] = "Sorry, this student  already existed";
    echoResponse(200, $response);
}
});



 $app->run();
?>
```

Comment: Make sure you actually are doing a POST request to /createstudent. Show example curl request and results.

Answer (score 0):

Slim framework has a great documentation and all post methods are shown in the documentation.

http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html

```
$app = new \Slim\App();
$app->post('/books', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    // Create new book
});
```

that is working. For more help you have to post your code and more informations. Bist way is to post your complete code.

Comment: I have added the complete code, the code am using is actually a tutorial from https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/php-restful-api-framework-slim-tutorial-1/